# Accessing SharePoint Files via Python Shareplum On Premise

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

We have a SharePoint 2013 site with a list of documents that I'm attempting to access with a python script.

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum.site import Version
from getpass import getpass as pwd
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

server_url = "https://sharepoint.company.net"
site_url = server_url + "/sites/<sitename>"
user_id = <user id>
pwd = pwd("Enter Password")

cred = HttpNtlmAuth(sid, pwd)
site = Site(site_url, auth=cred, version=Version.v2013)
```

This code works as it will return an error if the wrong credentials are provided:
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
and running the following will return data

```
site.GetListCollection()
```

and this data includes the folder I want to get the file listing for:

```
{'InternalName': '{<unique id>}',
  'Title': 'Documents',
  'Description': None,
  'BaseType': 'DocumentLibrary',
  'BaseTemplate': 'DocumentLibrary',
  'DefaultViewUrl': '/sites/<sitename>/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx',
  'LastModified': '2022-07-18 11:01:35Z',
  'InheritedSecurity': 'true',
  'AllowAnonymousAccess': 'false',
  'AnonymousViewListItems': 'false',
  'ReadSecurity': '1'},
```

however when the following is run:

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents')
```

it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:910, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    909 try:
--> 910     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    911 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    912     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    913     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

File C:\ds\tools\python3.8\latest\lib\json\__init__.py:357, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    354 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    355         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358 if cls is None:

File C:\ds\tools\python3.8\latest\lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334 containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336 """
--> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338 end = _w(s, end).end()

File C:\ds\tools\python3.8\latest\lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents')

File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\shareplum\site.py:418, in _Site365.Folder(self, folder_name)
    415 def Folder(self, folder_name):
    416     """Sharepoint Folder Web Service
    417     """
--> 418     return _Folder(self._session, folder_name, self.site_url)

File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\shareplum\folder.py:12, in _Folder.__init__(self, session, folder_name, url)
      9 self.site_url = url
     10 self.timeout = 3
---> 12 self.info = self._create_folder()

File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\shareplum\folder.py:30, in _Folder._create_folder(self)
     24 body = json.dumps(update_data)
     26 url = self.site_url + f"/_api/web/folders"
     28 headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
     29            'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
---> 30            'X-RequestDigest': self.contextinfo['FormDigestValue']}
     32 response = post(self._session, url=url, headers=headers, data=body, timeout=self.timeout)
     34 return response.json()

File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\shareplum\folder.py:17, in _Folder.contextinfo(self)
     14 @property
     15 def contextinfo(self):
     16     response = post(self._session, self.site_url + "/_api/contextinfo")
---> 17     data = response.json()
     18     return data

File c:\jpy\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:917, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    915     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.message)
    916 else:
--> 917     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:GetContextWebInformation xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:type="SP.ContextWebInformation">
    <d:FormDigestTimeoutSeconds m:type="Edm.Int32">1800</d:FormDigestTimeoutSeconds>
    <d:FormDigestValue>0xuniqueid,20 Jul 2022 19:26:02 -0000</d:FormDigestValue>
    <d:LibraryVersion>15.0.5067.1000</d:LibraryVersion>
    <d:SiteFullUrl>https://sharepoint.company.net/sites/sitename</d:SiteFullUrl>
    <d:SupportedSchemaVersions m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
        <d:element>14.0.0.0</d:element>
        <d:element>15.0.0.0</d:element>
    </d:SupportedSchemaVersions>
    <d:WebFullUrl>https://sharepoint.company.net/sites/sitename</d:WebFullUrl>
</d:GetContextWebInformation>: 0
```

not sure why.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had resolved this issue already, but 'Shared Documents' is a library within your site, not a folder.
You could get its content using site.List('Shared Folder').GetListItems()